# IsDeleted is not working in SubSonic 3.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, subsonic3

I'm using SubSonic 3.0 with SqlServer and for some reason the IsDeleted field is not being autopopulated to false. It remains null.

Is there a quick fix for this in the templates?

My field schema is
IsDeleted bit null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IsDeleted column should be created as NOT NULL.

Comment: You answered too fast I had to wait 7 minutes ;)